# Bounded wilcard not working for List inserted in Map

Tags: java, wildcard, nested-generics

The following code explains my problem:

```
interface f1 {}

interface f2 extends f1{}


1. List<? extends f1> l1 = new ArrayList<f2>();

2. Map<String, ? extends f1> m1 = new HashMap<String, f2>();

3. Map<String, List<? extends f1>> m2 = new HashMap<String, List<f2>>();
```

No. 1 and 2 work but no. 3 gives an error on eclipse. It says: **`Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,List<f2>> to Map<String,List<? extends f1>>`** Could you please help me figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Map<String, ? extends List<? extends f1>> m2 = new HashMap<String, List<f2>>();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works. Can you please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: When you do not use the wild card operator ? you specify exactly one specific type, e. g., String. You cannot do something like List<Object> l = new ArrayList<String>();
The same happens to the nested type arguments. You have a map containing strings and something which is extended from a list which contains something which is extended from f1.